# How to setup Travis in multilanguage (Nodejs client- Python server) environment?

Tags: travis-ci

I have a repo with a client and a server respectively based on NodeJs/Angular2 and Python/Django with approximately this folder structure:

```
main/
├── angular2-client/
│   ├── build/
│   ├── dist/
│   ├── node_modules/
│   ├── src/
│   └── ...
└── django-server/
    ├── myapp/
    ├── server/
    ├── manage.py
    └── ...
```

So, client and server are both on the same repo and same branch. What's the correct way of setting up Travis to build/deploy client and server to 2 different providers (eg. Firebase and AWS)?

Any suggestion, documentation reference or tutorial is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you simple split your repo into 2 subrepositories and use [git submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) to see it in one workspace?